# Cannot update and install any software after installing ClamAV?

Tags: software-center, updates, clamav

After I install Clam Antivirus I get an error: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/709447/.. When using Ubuntu Software Center I tried to repair the broken package but it give an error like this :

```
failedinstallArchives() failed: Preconfiguring packages ...

Preconfiguring packages ...

Preconfiguring packages ...

(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 139566 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking clamav-base (from .../clamav-base_0.97.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_all.deb) ...

dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:0>: data error'

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-base_0.97.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):

 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Processing triggers for man-db ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-base_0.97.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_all.deb

Error in function: 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav-freshclam:

 clamav-freshclam depends on clamav-base (>= 0.97.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2); however:

  Package clamav-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing clamav-freshclam (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav:

 clamav depends on clamav-freshclam | clamav-data; however:

  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.

  Package clamav-data is not installed.

  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing clamav (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamtk:

 clamtk depends on clamav (>= 0.95); however:

  Package clamav is not configured yet.

 clamtk depends on clamav-freshclam (>= 0.95) | clamav-data; however:

  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.

  Package clamav-data is not installed.

  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing clamtk (--configure):

 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Now I cannot install other software whether using Ubuntu Software Center or Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the package file is corrupted on disk.

Try

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/clamav-base_0.97.2+dfsg-1ubuntu2_all.deb
```

and repeat the operation.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved after 3 days.. I tried repaired using Ubuntu software center and it worked..